# How to change the color of text from a certain char to the end of the line

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a `WinForm` application that reads a text file. It reads the whole file line by line and generates a `RadioButton` when there is a delimiter at the start of the line.
So, `"|A Topic"` produces a `RadioButton` called `A Topic`.

During runtime, a user chooses a `RadioButton`, the application finds that line in the text file then reads all the text until the next delimiter and puts it into a `RichTextBox`.

The contents of the text file is actual Visual Basic code and I am looking for a way to delineate comments from the code.
I am trying to use `.Find()` to locate all of the apostrophes which signify a comment.

With a comment found, how can I expand the selection to the end of that line?

```
Dim index As Integer = 0

While index < RichTxtOut.Text.LastIndexOf("'")
    RichTxtOut.Find("'", index, RichTxtOut.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.None)
    RichTxtOut.SelectionColor = Color.Green

    index = RichTxtOut.Text.IndexOf("'", index) + 1
End While
```

This makes the apostrophe green, but how do I make the rest of the that line green.

Here is an update code _________________________________________________

```
Dim indexx As Integer = 0
Dim lines() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(FILE_NAME)
Dim numOfChars As Integer

While indexx < RichTxtOut.Text.LastIndexOf("'")
    numOfChars = 0

    RichTxtOut.Find("'", indexx, RichTxtOut.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.None)

    'count the number of characters after the apostrophe
    For li As Integer = 0 To Lines(RichTxtOut.GetLineFromCharIndex(RichTxtOut.Find("'", indexx, RichTxtOut.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.None))).Count - 1
        numOfChars += 1
    Next

    RichTxtOut.Select(RichTxtOut.Find("'", indexx, RichTxtOut.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.None), numOfChars)

    RichTxtOut.SelectionColor = Color.Green
    numOfChars = 0
    indexx = RichTxtOut.Text.IndexOf("'", indexx) + 1
End While
```

However It is still not working correctly. It is not finding the correct number of characters to in the line after the apostrophe.

Any suggestions??

Comment: You'd need to select from `RichTxtOut.Text.LastIndexOf("'")` to len(RichTxtOut.Text)` or something like that.

Comment: That expands the selection from the apostrophe to the end of the RichTxtOut feild. making everything green from there on.

Comment: If I made a loop that read each character and added to a counter, from the apostrophe on. How could I stop the loop before it went to the next line?

Comment: `Dim FirstChar as Interger = [string].IndexOf(CharW(39))` returns the Index of the first char it finds. The next char is `Dim NextChar as Interger = [string].IndexOf(CharW(39), FirstChar + 1)`. Then `[RichTextBox].Select(FirstChar, NextChar - FirstChar)`. Btw, this is `VB.Net` code.

Answer (score 0):

RichTextBoxes can be complicated, as they are quite powerful and have lots of ways to do things.

There's an example [here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/richtextbox) that sets colours by adding words one at a time, and setting the selection colour for each one (presumably making use of the fact that the most recently added word is selected). You could add your text one line at a time, and set the colour to green if the first (non-space) character is an apostrophe.

Using the selection is a bit of a hack though. The WPF RTB uses Paragraph and InLine objects, similar to DIVs and SPANs in HTML. You can set a font for each Inline. I'm not sure if the winforms one is the same.